# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Polly.CircuitBreaker.AsyncCircuitBreaker' to 'Polly.Policy'

Tags: c#, .net-core, timeout, polly, circuit-breaker

I am trying to create a combined resilience strategy for my Rest clients and for this I have written the following :

```
private static Policy circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy
     .Handle<TimeoutException>()
     .CircuitBreakerAsync(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

And I am getting the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Polly.CircuitBreaker.AsyncCircuitBreaker` to `Polly.Policy`

What am I missing ? I have checked a number of references online but I cannot come across a concise enough explanation of what causes this issue.

Usage :
Eventually I want to combine the CircuitBreaker policy above with a `WaitandRetry` policy but I cannot figure out how to extract the combined policy :

(This is working)

```
public static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> CreateResiliencePolicy()
{
    var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
 
    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Polly.Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt)),
        (result, timeSpan, context) =>
        {
        });
    
    return timeoutPolicy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy);
}
```

This is what I want (Not working) :

```
public static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> CreateResiliencePolicy()
{
    var circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<TimeoutException>()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Polly.Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt)),
        (result, timeSpan, context) =>
        {
        });
   
    return circuitBreakerPolicy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy);

     //I want to do this instead
     //public static Policy resilientAsyncStrategy =circuitBreakerPolicy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy);

     //Then return resilientAsyncStrategy
     //return resilientAsyncStrategy;
}
```

And then use the returned policy instance as :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PaymentDetailDto>> GetAsync()
{
    var items = await resilientAsyncStrategy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await client.GetAsync());
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Polly defines the following four abstract Policy types:

- [Policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Policy.cs)
- [Policy < TResult >](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Policy.TResult.cs)
- [AsyncPolicy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/AsyncPolicy.cs)
- [Async < TResult >](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/AsyncPolicy.TResult.cs)

|  | Method | Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sync | `Policy` | `Policy<TResult>` |
| Async | `AsyncPolicy` | `AsyncPolicy<TResult>` |

So, in your case the `circuitBreakerPolicy` should be defined like this:

```
private static AsyncPolicy circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy
     .Handle<TimeoutException>()
     .CircuitBreakerAsync(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

---

Whenever you want to combine / chain two (or more) policies then you should consider to use `PolicyWrap` ([reference](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap)). Please bear in mind that policy chain works in an [escalation way](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc) which means if the inner policy can't handle the problem then it will propagate that to the next outer policy.

Please also bear in mind that policies should be compatible with each other. So, if one of them is async then other one should be as well. If the inner returns something then the outer should do the same.

So, your `CreateResiliencePolicy` could look like this:

```
public static AsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> CreateResilienceStrategy()
{
    var circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
        .Handle<TimeoutException>()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Polly.Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt)),
        (result, timeSpan, context) =>
        {
        });

    return Policy.WrapAsync(circuitBreakerPolicy, waitAndRetryPolicy);
}
```

Please also bear in mind that ordering matters:

1. `Policy.WrapAsync(circuitBreakerPolicy, waitAndRetryPolicy)` you have an inner Retry and an outer CB
2. `Policy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy, circuitBreakerPolicy)` you have an inner CB and an outer Retry

The following two lines are equivalent:

```
circuitBreakerPolicy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy);
Policy.WrapAsync(circuitBreakerPolicy, waitAndRetryPolicy)
```

If you want to change the ordering of the policies then your strategy will work in a different way. If you want to use the CB as inner policy and the retry as outer then you should amend the `waitAndRetryPolicy` to handle `BrokenCircuitException` as well.

Couple of months ago I have put together a [sample application](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/ResilienceServiceDesignDemo/ResilienceServiceDesignDemo/Program.cs) which demonstrates how can you incrementally design your resilience strategy.

---

**UPDATE**: Add sample code

### Testing the retry logic

I've used the following console app to test your retry policy:

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var strategy = CreateResilienceStrategy();
    await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) =>
        await client.GetAsync("https://httpstat.us/500", ct)
        , CancellationToken.None);
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}

public static AsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> CreateResilienceStrategy()
{
    var circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
        .Handle<TimeoutException>()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            onBreak: (_, __) => Console.WriteLine("Break"),
            onReset: () => Console.WriteLine("Reset"),
            onHalfOpen: () => Console.WriteLine("HalfOpen"));

    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Polly.Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt)),
        onRetryAsync: (_, ts, ___) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Retry, penalty: {ts.Seconds} secs");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

    return Policy.WrapAsync(circuitBreakerPolicy, waitAndRetryPolicy);
}
```

The output:

```
Retry, penalty: 3 secs
Retry, penalty: 9 secs
Retry, penalty: 27 secs
Finished
```

As you can see,

- it had performed all retries without luck
- it did not trigger the circuit breaker
- `strategy.ExecuteAsync` returned a response where the status code is 500
- it continued the work after the Http call

### Testing the circuit breaker logic

Because the CB policy was setup to trigger for `TimeoutException` that's why I set the `client.Timeout` to 1 millisecond in the `Main`. With that the application crashes with `TaskCanceledException`.

It does that because HttpClient throws `TaskCanceledException` in case of Timeout instead of `TimeoutException`. If you would use polly's Timeout policy then you would receive `TimeoutRejectedException`.

So, here is my amended to code to be able to test CB

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
    var strategy = CreateResilienceStrategy();
    try
    {
        await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) =>
            await client.GetAsync("https://httpstat.us/500", ct)
            , CancellationToken.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed with " + ex.GetType().Name);
    }    
}

public static AsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> CreateResilienceStrategy()
{
    var circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
        .Handle<OperationCanceledException>()
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            onBreak: (_, __) => Console.WriteLine("Break"),
            onReset: () => Console.WriteLine("Reset"),
            onHalfOpen: () => Console.WriteLine("HalfOpen"));

    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Polly.Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<OperationCanceledException>()
        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt)),
        onRetryAsync: (_, ts, ___) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Retry, penalty: {ts.Seconds} secs");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

    return Policy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy, circuitBreakerPolicy);
}
```

Modifications:

- Set the timeout to 1 milliseconds
- Changed the consecutive failed count of CB from 3 to 1
- Changed the chaining: retry outer, cb inner
- Added `OperationCanceledException` conditions for both policies

The output

```
Break
Retry, penalty: 3 secs
HalfOpen
Break
Retry, penalty: 9 secs
HalfOpen
Break
Retry, penalty: 27 secs
HalfOpen
Break
Failed with OperationCanceledException
```

Comment: The line  " Policy.WrapAsync(circuitBreakerPolicy, waitAndRetryPolicy); "    shows exception Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryPolicy <System.Net.HttpResponseMessage>to Polly.IAsyncPolicy

Comment: @Golide I've extended my post with 2 sample applications which shows that the provided code works. If you still experience some error or exception please let me know. Please also try to share as many details regarding that as possible.

Comment: @Golide Did the suggested solution work for you? Do you need any further information?

Comment: I have implemented the console app , works perfectly. I will update (within the day) once im done testing the same in the  WebAPI ...

Comment: @Golide Have you had a chance to test it in a WebAPI project?

Comment: I have  an error "no overload for method 'GetAsync' takes 1 argument" . I am using RestEase with HttpClient as follows :  public PaymentClient(IConfiguration configuration, IDiscoveryClient discoveryClient)
        {
            var handler = new DiscoveryHttpClientHandler(discoveryClient);
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler, false)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("PricingServiceUri"))
            };
            client = RestClient.For<IPaymentClient>(httpClient);
        }

Comment: public async Task<IEnumerable<PaymentDetailDto>> GetAsync()
        {
            var strategy = ResilienceStrategy();
            try
            {
                var items =  await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) =>
                    await client.GetAsync("www.htttp.com", ct)
                    , CancellationToken.None);
                Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               
            }
           
            return items;
        }

Comment: @Golide Which GetAsync shows this error? In the provided code you have a couple of them...

Comment: await client.GetAsync("www.htttp.com", ct) , CancellationToken.None);  .This is the instance of RestClient ... taken from client = RestClient.For<IPaymentClient>(httpClient);

Comment: @Golide I'm not familiar with RestEase. But based on the provided error message, I suspect it is a compilation error. The message says there is no overload which anticipates a single parameter. On the other hand your provided code shows that you are calling with two. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I have reverted to  this form which seems to be working (not errors). Confirm the resilienceStrategy is being applied correctly ? public async Task<IEnumerable<PaymentDetailDto>> GetAsync()
        {
           
            var items = await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () => (HttpResponseMessage)await client.GetAsync());
            return (IEnumerable<PaymentDetailDto>)items;
        }

Comment: @Golide The CancellationToken is only needed of you want to apply Timeout policy as well. Otherwise you can omit it, just like you did.

Comment: @Golide I want to emphasize that casting HttpResponseMessage directly to IEnumerable<PaymentDetailDto> feels wrong. Most probably you need to deserialize the response body to retieve the received data. But I think this is out of scope for this question.